# Facebook Open Graph images not displaying in Chrome; Displaying in Firefox fine

Tags: php, facebook, google-chrome, sdk

After wrestling with Facebook's new Open Graph/SDK, I've noticed the images I retrieve with no problem in Firefox are not displaying **at all** in Chrome.

Example:
When the following tag is rendered on a webpage
`<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/angrybirds/picture">`

Firefox displays it with no problem while Chrome displays nothing.
Is this a scripting error on my end or is this something that I need to work around to accommodate for Chrome?

PHP 5
Firefox 7.0.1
Google Chrome 14.0.835.202

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a local caching problem, the link is working wonderful for me in chrome.

Please provide us a little more of you code if still got problems like this after clearing your cache.

Comment: @Tamas-Pap I tried clearing the cache and still it did not render the images on this machine, which leads me to believe that these images would not display on another machine.

As for including more of my code, I would be happy to...I just have no idea what chunk would point out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is not a cache problem?